# Meaning of "QMAKE_CFLAGS = -pipe"

Tags: qt, qmake, mxe

I saw someplace someone specifying `QMAKE_CFLAGS = -pipe`. There wasn't any explanation beyond "to speed up build". How does it do that, and what are the alternative options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the variables `QMAKE_CFLAGS` (note:there are several variable with this prefix) will be forwarded to the C compiler, and doesn't have an influence on the qmake process.

Look at this SO thread to know what `-pipe` means for your compiler: [When should I use GCC's -pipe option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512933/when-should-i-use-gccs-pipe-option)