# -pipe flag of cc on FreeBSD 10.x

Tags: clang, freebsd, cc

Yesterday i was working on FreeBSD jails. According to the documentation, I ran command `make buildworld` and it compiled lots of files using **cc**.
In logs i saw something like:

```
cc ... -pipe ... file.c
```

Now I'm curious about `-pipe` flag. I also searched in manual page but did not find anything about this flag.
Do you know what this flag exactly does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent an Email to Salvatore Sanfilippo (author of [Redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis)) and asked above question and he replied with:

> Hello, it simply will use Unix pipes instead of files in order to
>   "chain" the different stages needed for the compilation process. When
>   -pipe is used, as GCC starts to emit the assembler code, the assembler
>   will start to read from the pipe and emit the machine code and so
>   forth. It should optimize compilation speed, but in practice it helps
>   very little AFAIK.

Thanks to him.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `cc` is Clang, a detailed man page was added in later versions of Clang that are not available on your FreeBSD version. The `-pipe` is described as:

```
-pipe, --pipe
Use pipes between commands, when possible
```

See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-pipe

Comment: Thank you. but do you know what this exactly does in compilation ?

Comment: I have no special knowledge about that. GCC has the same switch, and I assume they are equivalent. There's an excellent explanation for GCC here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512933/when-should-i-use-gccs-pipe-option